# Python multiprocessing on OpenCV images

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, opencv, multiprocessing, multicore

I need to accelerate some image processing by means of multithreading on a multicore architecture.

My images are OpenCV objects.

I tried approaching the problem with the `threading` module, but it turns out not to perform true parallelism (!) because of the GIL issue. I have tried with the `multiprocessing` module, but it turns out that my objects are not shared between processes (!)

My processing needs to work on different sections of the same image simultaneously (so that the Queue paradigm is irrelevant).

What can I do ?

Comment: Just FYI, images from OpenCV in Python are actually numpy `ndarray` instances, not OpenCV objects. Any parallelism would be identical to parallelizing numpy array operations, which you may actually find some good info for online. There are often natural ways to operate on multiple images at once in numpy (just like operating on an entire image at once instead of pixel-by-pixel), but you still may need the threading module.

Comment: As such, changing one of your tags to numpy may help get better responses. I didn't want to edit this though since I'm not sure which tag you'd rather remove. Also see [here](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming). Most numpy operations are actually implemented in C and Fortran, and so if you vectorize properly, they skirt the GIL and operate in parallel. What operations are you looking to perform?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds They are sophisticated color conversions, all written in Python.

Comment: If you would give a little more information about what operations you are doing and where the bottlenecks might be prominent, it would be easier doing suggestion. Like what is the resolution of your image? Moving Data is very costly.

Comment: @user1767754: they are function calls for every individual pixel, seen as blackboxes. Up to 24 Mpixels RGB. Currently taking hours on a single core. Rewriting/optimizing these functions is currently not an option.

Comment: "they are function calls for every individual pixel, seen as blackboxes." yikes. Yeah I wouldn't even use Python if that's the case. Or at the very least, I'd consider Cython.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds: this will eventually be completely rewritten in C++. In this prototyping stage, I don't have the option of switching tools. Too costly.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a solution here to share NumPy arrays when using the multiprocessing model: http://briansimulator.org/sharing-numpy-arrays-between-processes/

The main idea is to flatten the image bitmap as a linear buffer, copy it to a shared array, and map it back to a bitmap (without copy) in the receiving processes.

This is not fully satisfying as multithreading would be more resource-friendly than multiprocessing (it takes a huge amount of memory), but at least it works, with minimal effort.